# How to set one element in array null when set array?

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I want fil new datarow from int array. I set the array and I want that one cell in the middle of array will be null. How I need to set the element null in the array?

I tried "null","DBNull.Value" it's not works.

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
int[] codCell = { v1, v2, Null,v3};
while (i < codCell.Length)
{
    dr[i] = codCell[i];
    i++;
}
myTable.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: The array elements are of type `int` which is not a nullable type. Therefor you can't set an element in the array to `null`. You should use `int?`, which is a nullable type

Answer (score 0):

Theres 2 issues here, 1 is that you need to use int? for arrays if you want nulls (as Stefan says).  The other is that in a DataTable you should set the value as `DBNull.value`.

Also unless `myTable` and `dt` are the same instance you have to use `ImportRow` to copy the row into the other table.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("V1",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("V2",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("V3",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("V4",typeof(int));

DataTable myTable = dt.Clone();

int v1 = 1;
int v2 = 2;
int v3 = 3;

int i = 0;

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
int?[] codCell = { v1, v2, null, v3 };
while (i < codCell.Length)
{
    dr[i] = codCell[i] ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
    i++;
}

myTable.ImportRow(dr);
```